# Jest mock function returns undefined instead of object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocking, jestjs, jwt

I'm trying to create unit tests for my auth middleware in an Express app.

The middleware is as simple as this:

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

const auth = (req, res, next) => {
    const tokenHeader = req.headers.auth; 

    if (!tokenHeader) {
        return res.status(401).send({ error: 'No token provided.' });
    }

    try {
        const decoded = jwt.verify(tokenHeader, process.env.JWT_SECRET);

        if (decoded.id !== req.params.userId) {
            return res.status(403).json({ error: 'Token belongs to another user.' });
        }

        return next();
    } catch (err) {
        return res.status(401).json({ error: 'Invalid token.' });
    }
}

module.exports = auth;
```

And this is my test, where I want to ensure that if the token is ok everything will go smoothly and the middleware just calls `next()`:

```
it('should call next when everything is ok', async () => {
        req.headers.auth = 'rgfh4hs6hfh54sg46';
        jest.mock('jsonwebtoken/verify', () => {
            return jest.fn(() => ({ id: 'rgfh4hs6hfh54sg46' }));
        });
        await auth(req, res, next);
        expect(next).toBeCalled();
});
```

But instead of returning the object with and id field as desired, the mock always returns undefined. I have tried returning the object instead of jest.fn() but it didn't work too.

I know there are some similar threads here on stack overflow but unfortunately none of the solutions proposed worked for me.

If more context is needed, [here](https://pastebin.com/q0PyUXTZ) is my full test suite. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to solve this is to mock the `jsonwebtoken` module and then use `mockReturnValue` on the method to be mocked. Consider this example:

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

jest.mock('jsonwebtoken');

jwt.verify.mockReturnValue({ id: 'rgfh4hs6hfh54sg46' });

it('should correctly mock jwt.verify', () => {
  expect(jwt.verify("some","token")).toStrictEqual({ id: 'rgfh4hs6hfh54sg46' })
});
```